# jquery url string manipulation

Tags: jquery, url

I have two cases here.

1. `/abc/qsc/rs#AS626`
2. `#AS626`

All the URLs in a page are coming dynamically. In some cases I need to put the full URL as point 1. In some case I need to use only the hash as point 2.

For example:

In some places i want it as href="/abc/qsc/rs#AS626" and in some places i need as href="#AS262". So i have tried using `#AS` which is common, to split it. But in both the places either it puts the full url or it puts the id's.

This is done only for IE7 to have the urls as normal ones because in IE7 it takes along with the http.

Comment: How do you mean 'manipulate' it? I assume this is an ID of some kind, are you wanting to query a database with it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the hash value using jQuery?

Comment: I don't understand the question. In which way do you want to manipulate it? And I don't truly understand what exactly you want to manipulate... Could you be more specific?

Comment: In some places i want it as href="/abc/qsc/rs#AS626" and in some places i need as href="#AS262". So haow can i achieve it?

Comment: 1. Where do you need to put this? 2. Based on what criteria do you need to put either one or the other? 3. Are you having difficulties with separating the string into the hash part and the other part, or with coding up your site so the 'right' version ends up in the right place?

In any case, a jsfiddle would definitely help.

Comment: @Gijs i have two anchors tags in a page. i have to have like this <a href="/abc/qsc/rs#AS626">test</a> and <a href="#AS626">abc</a> in the same page. how can i achieve it? The url is dynamic and i have only #AS to use it.

Comment: You only answered the first question I asked. Without answers to 2 and 3 I don't understand what your question is, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var s = '/abc/qsc/rs#AS626';
var whatYouWant = s.substring(s.indexOf('#'));
```

In case you know there will be a #. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bs38V/6/

Comment: @anders thanks, i have already getting the ids, my doubt is i have two anchors tags in a page. <a href="/abc/qsc/rs#AS626">test</a> and <a href="#AS626">abc</a> in the same page. how can i achieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want to change the href of all links on the page?